# Alternatives to xargs -l

Tags: bash, shell, find, xargs, busybox

I want to rename a bunch of dirs from DIR to DIR.OLD. Ideally I would use the following:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name \"*.y\" -mtime +`expr 2 \* 365` -print0 | xargs -0 -r -I file mv file file.old
```

But the machine I want to execute this on has BusyBox installed and the BusyBox xargs doesn't support the "-I" option.

What are some common alternative methods for collecting an array of files and then executing on them in a shell script?

Comment: What is the \" about? That would tell find to list files called exactly `"*.y"` (the quotes will be passed to find and while the * will be expanded by shell, it will find nothing and passed through anyway), which I doubt exist.

Comment: Among the various compile-time options for busybox are `CONFIG_FEATURE_FIND_PRINT0`, `CONFIG_FEATURE_FIND_EXEC`, `CONFIG_FEATURE_FIND_EXEC_PLUS` -- approaches will or won't work depending on the details of exactly how *your* copy was compiled.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `-exec` and `{}` features of the `find` command so you don't need any pipes at all:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "*.y" -mtime +`expr 2 \* 365` -exec mv "{}" "{}.old" \;
```

Also you don't need to specify '.' path - this is default for `find`. And you used extra slashes in `"*.y"`. Of course if your file names do not really contain quotes.

In fairness it should be noted, that version with `while read` loop is the fastest of proposed here. Here are some example measurements:

```
$ cat measure 
#!/bin/sh
case $2 in
  1) find "$1" -print0 | xargs -0 -I file echo mv file file.old ;;

  2) find "$1" -exec echo mv '{}' '{}.old' \; ;;

  3) find "$1" | while read file; do
       echo mv "$file" "$file.old"
     done;;
esac
$ time ./measure android-ndk-r5c 1 | wc
   6225   18675  955493
real    0m6.585s
user    0m18.933s
sys     0m4.476s
$ time ./measure android-ndk-r5c 2 | wc
   6225   18675  955493
real    0m6.877s
user    0m18.517s
sys     0m4.788s
$ time ./measure android-ndk-r5c 3 | wc
   6225   18675  955493
real    0m0.262s
user    0m0.088s
sys     0m0.236s
```

I think it's because `find` and `xargs` invokes additional /bin/sh (actually `exec(3)` does it) every time for execute a command, while shell `while` loop do not.

**Upd:** If your busybox version was compiled without `-exec` option support for the `find` command then the `while` loop or `xargs`, suggested in the other answers ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8759463/566344), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8759430/566344)), is your way.

Comment: +1: The find command comes with the `-exec` option. It's a bit slower than `xargs` because it executes the command for each and every file found. But, it works, and it doesn't have _whitespace_ issues because the shell isn't involved. If you can't use `xargs` because of whitespace issues, use `-exec`. Loops are just as inefficient as the `-exec` parameter since they execute once for each and every file, but have the whitespace issues that `xargs` have.

Comment: `xargs` also executes the command for each file in this case so `find` is not slower.

Comment: You're right. I didn't look at the command. Normally you use xargs instead of `-exec` because xargs combines as many files as it can on the command line and executes the command only a few times.

Comment: wrong; it is because find and exec do not run shells so must exec /bin/echo for each file. if we modify the script to use /bin/echo then the time is comparable to the first two options; adding an option `find "$1" -printf "mv %p %p.old\n"` runs faster than the builtin echo.

Comment: This doesn't work as written, because Busybox doesn't support the -exec option to find.  The while loop approach posted by Jan Hudec works on Busybox

Comment: @DavidW., re: "slower", `-exec ... {} +` behaves just as xargs does (in terms of minimizing the invocation count), and has been part of the POSIX standard for `find` since 2006.

Comment: In busybox '-exec' option support is configurable at compile time just like the 'find' command itself. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use a `for` loop. Unfortunately I don't think busybox understands `read -0` either, so you won't be able to handle newlines properly. If you don't need to, it's easiest to just:

   ```
   find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name \"*.y\" -mtime +`expr 2 \* 365` -print | while read file; do mv -- "$file" "$file".old; done
   ```
2. Use a `sh -c` as the command. Note the slightly weird use of `$0` to name the first argument (it would normally be the script name and that goes to `$0` and while you are suppressing script with `-c`, the argument still goes to `$0`) and the use of `-n 1` to avoid batching.

   ```
   find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name \"*.y\" -mtime +`expr 2 \* 365` -print0 | xargs -0 -r -n 1 sh -c 'mv -- "$0" "$0".old'
   ```

**Edit** *Oops: I forgot about the `find -exec` again.*

Comment: Busybox doesn't even understand print0.  But your whie loop works

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use a loop:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name \"*.y\" -mtime +`expr 2 \* 365` -print | while IFS= read file
do
    mv "$file" "$file".old
done
```

Comment: `read` uses newline as separator. Either you need `read -0` (but I am not sure it's implemented in busybox) or you need just `-print`.